# Powershell - Change format of output

Tags: powershell, csv

How can I change the presenation of the output my code produces:

```
$apps = Import-CSV apps.csv
$computers = Import-CSV compobj.csv
foreach($computer in $computers) {    
    $computerLob = $computer.lob
    $lobApps = $apps | ? {$_.lob -eq $computerLob }
    foreach($app in $lobApps){
       $computerHostname = $computer.hostname
       $appLocation = $app.location
       $installed=Test-Path "\\$computerHostname\$appLocation"      
       New-Object PSObject @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} 
    }
}
```

I would like for the presentation of the code to be changed. This is how it looks like:

```
Name                         Value                                                                                                            
----                         -----                                                                                                            
Installed                    True                                                                                                             
App                          App1                                                                 
Computer                     171.159.192.10
Installed                    True                                                                                                             
App                          App2                                                                         
Computer                     171.159.192.10
```

I'd like for it to look like this:

```
Computer                 App1    App2
-----------              ------    -----
171.159.192.10           True     True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the hashtable to `New-Object` as its ctor argument instead of a property set. Change it to:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  Computer=$computer.hostname
  App=$app.appname
  Installed=$installed
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Having the same issue as above. I'm getting the columns in the following order `Installed,App,Computer` - can I have it in the following order: `Computer,App,Installed`.

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier: Can't you pick any order with `select` statement in Powershell?

Comment: @Neolisk - can you show me a quick example please. Not sure how it works when you create an new object. I've been trying to switch the order in `-Property @{...}`

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier: Whichever is not captured, is delivered onto a pipeline. Wrap your code into a function, call this function from your main code, then add a `| select Computer,App,Installed` to that. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @Neolisk Unfortunately not :(. I'm fairly new to all this. Can you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PowerShell V3, rather than use new-object you can do this:

```
[pscustomobject]@{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed}
```

On V2, don't forget to use the `-Property` parameter e.g.:

```
new-object psobject -property @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed}
```

And to force the output order you can use Format-Table:

```
$obj = new-object psobject -property @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} 
$obj | Format-Table Computer,App,Installed
```

Comment: This works great! But I'm getting the columns in the following order `Installed,App,Computer` - can I have it in the following order: `Computer,App,Installed`. Tried playing around with the order of everything but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Interesting, I get the properties in that order on my system with PowerShell v4 now.  You can always use Format-Table to select the specific order you want `new-object ... | Format-Table Computer,App,Installed`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean (a follow-up to OP's question asked in comments, too big to fit there):

```
function MyFunction(){
  $apps = Import-CSV apps.csv
  $computers = Import-CSV compobj.csv
  foreach($computer in $computers) {    
    $computerLob = $computer.lob
    $lobApps = $apps | ? {$_.lob -eq $computerLob }
    foreach($app in $lobApps){
      $computerHostname = $computer.hostname
      $appLocation = $app.location
      $installed=Test-Path "\\$computerHostname\$appLocation"      
      New-Object PSObject @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} 
    }
  }
}

MyFunction | select Computer,App,Installed
```

A reduced test case to prove the above should work:

```
function MyFunction(){
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Computer="computer"
    App="app"
    Installed="installed"
  }
}

MyFunction | select Computer,App,Installed
```